# Firebase "session_start" event is fired more than 10 seconds from when App is on the foreground

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Hi I'm working with Firebase and Google-Analytics for firebase. 
I saw an firebase blog post Recently(not quite recent but) published, It saids the latest updated Firebase SDK provides "session_start" event with no-time delay like 10 seconds.

(here's the posts. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/12/new-changes-sessions-user-engagement.html)

> "......Google Analytics for Firebase will trigger a session_start event as soon as your app goes into the foreground now. There's no more 10 second delay."

But my logs(from BigQuery) shows "session_start" event fired 10 seconds after the user_engagement event.

So, i found some document about the session_start, it seems that i can sets the minium session duration
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setSessionTimeoutDuration(long))

So Here's my question,
 Can I sets the minium session duration to 0 seconds? I want to fire "session_start" event as soon as user opens my App, or App is on the foreground.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [`FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).setMinimumSessionDuration`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#public-void-setminimumsessionduration-long-milliseconds) as you mentioned.

Note that this is now deprecated, and that messing with these values is generally not advised as it [can negatively affect reporting](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-cpp/issues/2).

Comment: Thanks! As you said, the method is now deprecated. Instead we updated Android Firebase core SDK version to 16.0.9 which is released at may 2019 and it solved the problem.